# Cooldowns Using Pygame Timer

Tags: python, pygame

I'm very new to coding and am trying to figure out how to properly use the Pygame timer for cooldowns. Currently I would like for the sprite (Player) to (when spacebar is pressed or held) boost for a super short period of time. I want there to be a small cooldown between each boost that they can use so that its not spammable or holdable. So far it only works once at the start and then the else statements are used. I fail to see the problem in my code which there obviously is.

```
boost_cooldown = pygame.USEREVENT +1

self.attacking = False
        self.cooldown = False

    def update(self):
        self.acc = vec(0,0)

        pressed_keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if pressed_keys[K_a]:
            self.acc.x += -ACC
        if pressed_keys[K_d]:
            self.acc.x += ACC
        if pressed_keys[K_w]:
            self.acc.y += -ACC
        if pressed_keys[K_s]:
            self.acc.y += ACC

        if pressed_keys[K_SPACE]:
            if pressed_keys[K_a]:
                if self.cooldown == False:
                    self.acc.x += -ACC2
                    self.cooldown = True
                    pygame.time.set_timer(boost_cooldown, 1000)
                else:
                    print("error (cooldown)")
            if pressed_keys[K_d]:
                if self.cooldown == False:
                    self.acc.x += ACC2
                    self.cooldown = True
                    pygame.time.set_timer(boost_cooldown, 1000)
                else:
                    print("error (cooldown)")
            if pressed_keys[K_w]:
                if self.cooldown == False:
                    self.acc.y += -ACC2
                    self.cooldown = True
                    pygame.time.set_timer(boost_cooldown, 1000)
                else:
                    print("error (cooldown)")
            if pressed_keys[K_s]:
                if self.cooldown == False:
                    self.acc.y += ACC2
                    self.cooldown = True
                    pygame.time.set_timer(boost_cooldown, 1000)
                else:
                    print("error (cooldown)")

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == boost_cooldown:
                self.cooldown = False
                pygame.time.set_timer(boost_cooldown, 0)
```

Comment: You could instead just keep track of the time that the player used the boost, and check that it hasn't been less than X milliseconds since that last time. I feel like that would be a a way simpler way of doing it.

Comment: What can I use to track milliseconds? Still the Pygame timer?

Comment: `time.time()` could work, might as well give it a shot I'd think. Not that you should just ignore pygame timers though but they might not be the perfect thing for what you need, you might find that using `time()` is simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it thanks to Random Davis, took me a while to learn how to start the loop but I posted the fixed code if anyone needs.

```py
ACC = 0.8
ACC2 = 20
start_time = 0
 

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__() 
        self.surf = pygame.Surface((30, 30))
        self.surf.fill((128,255,40))
        self.rect = self.surf.get_rect()
   
        self.pos = vec((10, 385))
        self.vel = vec(0,0)
        self.acc = vec(0,0)


    def update(self):
        self.acc = vec(0,0)
        global start_time

        pressed_keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if pressed_keys[K_a]:
            self.acc.x += -ACC
        if pressed_keys[K_d]:
            self.acc.x += ACC
        if pressed_keys[K_w]:
            self.acc.y += -ACC
        if pressed_keys[K_s]:
            self.acc.y += ACC

        if pressed_keys[K_SPACE]:
            if pressed_keys[K_a]:
                if (pygame.time.get_ticks() - start_time) >= 1000:
                    start_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
                    self.acc.x += -ACC2
                else:
                    print("error")
            if pressed_keys[K_d]:
                if (pygame.time.get_ticks() - start_time) >= 1000:
                    start_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
                    self.acc.x += ACC2
                else:
                    print("error")
            if pressed_keys[K_w]:
                if (pygame.time.get_ticks() - start_time) >= 1000:
                    start_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
                    self.acc.y += -ACC2
                else:
                    print("error")
            if pressed_keys[K_s]:
                if (pygame.time.get_ticks() - start_time) >= 1000:
                    start_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
                    self.acc.y += ACC2
                else:
                    print("error")

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
     
    displaysurface.fill((0,0,0))
 
    P1.update()
    for entity in all_sprites:
        displaysurface.blit(entity.surf, entity.rect)
    
    pygame.display.update()
    Clock.tick(FPS)
```